# How to get partial sum of column and finds which rows has partial sum in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
+----------------------------------------+
|        Here is my sample table         |
+----------------------------------------+
| Date       Person    Column_1    Column_2 |
| 15-03-13    A       100         NULL   |
| 15-03-13    B       NULL         100   |
| 16-03-13    A       100           50   |
| 16-03-13    B       NULL         NULL  |
| 17-03-13    A       100           50   |
| 17-03-13    B       20            30   |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Now i wanted to do sum(column_1) by date. But i also need to which sum of row includes NULL data.
here is the output result I wanted to achieve

```
+---------------------------------+
| Date       SUM  includesNullval |
+---------------------------------+
| 15-03-13   100   true           |
| 16-03-13   100   true           |
| 17-03-13   120   false          |
+---------------------------------+
```

I don't know to achieve above output. Can anybody give me any idea or solution of this problem?

Comment: @Strawberry i'm using mysql.

Comment: @Strawberry updated the date values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note both the form and content of the answer.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(date DATE NOT NULL
,person CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,column_1 INT NULL
,column_2 INT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(date,person)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('2013-03-15','A', 100, NULL),
('2013-03-15','B',NULL,  100),
('2013-03-16','A', 100,   50),
('2013-03-16','B',NULL, NULL),
('2013-03-17','A', 100,   50),
('2013-03-17','B',  20,   30);

SELECT date, SUM(column_1), MAX(column_2 IS NULL) incnull FROM my_table GROUP BY date;
+------------+---------------+---------+
| date       | SUM(column_1) | incnull |
+------------+---------------+---------+
| 2013-03-15 |           100 |       1 |
| 2013-03-16 |           100 |       1 |
| 2013-03-17 |           120 |       0 |
+------------+---------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a case statement will help you here:

```
Select Date_Column, sum(column_A), 
MAX(CASE when column_A is NULL then 'True' else 'False' end) "Includes_NULL_Value"
from table_x
group by Date_column;
```

[REX TESTER](http://rextester.com/TIX44510)

Comment: Oh, nice use of MAX there ;-)

Comment: @Strawberry I used CASE in group by but that didnt work out so had to use an aggregate ;-)